# Specify original msi install location for msp file using a command line switch

Tags: sccm, msi

Using SCCM 2012 I have deployed Autodesk Revit 2014 to my users. The install uses an underlying "RVT2014.msi".  Now I would like to push out Update Release 2 which is an ".msp" file.  I would like the update to run silent on the user's machine but in the middle of the install it prompts for the original install msi location with a message:

> The feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is
>   unavailable.

Unfortunately the existing source that it is trying to use no longer exists and so I need to point it to the new location where the "RVT2014.msi" sits.  I am able to manually specify this location but I do not want to do this for 80+ users and would prefer to update the SCCM deployment so that it will automatically and silently look for "RVT2014.msi" in its new location.

Are there any ways to accomplish this by passing a command line switches to msiexec or through some other method?

Comment: What install command are you currently using?

Comment: @BigHomie I'm currently using "msiexec /p 'Update.msp'".

Comment: I'm not near my environment right now, can you try `msiexec /i \\serv\share\NewRVT2014.msi PATCH=msipatch.msp /qb`, pointing msiexec to the new location of your .msi. I dont' know if this will un/reinstall Autodesk or not. Another thing to try is placing that .msi back into the location the clients are looking for, that may or may not work, if it does I'll make an official answer.

Comment: @BigHomie Thanks, your first suggestion worked.  Make sure to put that in an answer and I will accept it.  I'm sure that the second suggestion will work as well but it requires more work and it's less maintainable since the original install location is a place that SCCM controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `msiexec /i \\serv\share\NewRVT2014.msi PATCH=msipatch.msp /qb`, pointing msiexec to the new location of your .msi. This may un/reinstall Autodesk, or just patch it.

Another thing to try is placing that .msi back into the location the clients are looking for, that may or may not work, and may or may not be scalable depending on your environment.